# Measuring video volume level at any chosen point

Tags: video, audio

I'm interested in measuring video volume level (in dB) at any chosen time in the video. I mean measuring per file, not per speakers, of course. What I'm talking about is either a software where you can load the video and get data about the volume levels while watching, or a tool where you can type the requested timecodes and get data about their volume levels.

Answer (score 1):

By using [moviepy](http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/index.html) you can load a movie and perform a number of manipulations on it including separating the sound from the movie, (or a clip at specific times), and can then get the sound levels, (in a range -1.0 to 1.0), (the actual volume depends on your volume control & speakers of course and the perceived volume depends on a number of factors including the listener).

You can get the normalized sound level at any point in time, (one or two numbers depending if the movie is mono or stereo), using `VideoFileClip(`*filename*`).audio.get_frame(`*time*`)` or even convert the soundtrack to a numeric array with `VideoFileClip(`*filename*`).audio.to_soundarray()` and then you have access to all of the plotting functions available from the various [python](https://www.python.org) libraries such as [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/).

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170548/using-python-to-measure-audio-loudness) stack overflow question for some discussion of loudness.